# `gedit` assertion failure `GTK_IS_TREE_SELECTION (selection)`

Tags: 12.04, gedit

I am seeing assertion failures in `gedit` on a fairly fresh install of Precise.  This does not happen on every invocation of gedit but only if I `Edit > Preferences`.  The assertion failure happens upon closing the preferences dialog.  Since it relies on GTK, I suppose there is a chance that this is an installation problem.  How can I fix this?

> (gedit:3634): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_selection_get_selected:
>   assertion `GTK_IS_TREE_SELECTION (selection)' failed

By the way, this assertion failure is seen in `Terminal`.  If you launch `gedit` from the Ubuntu Unity Launcher, you will not see the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bug report was filled about that:

[Assertion failure when closing 'preferences' dialogue in gedit 3.4.1](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676694)